# Get records matching regex in Ms-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using query as follows to get any records that begins with any character, has bunch of 0s and ends with number (1 in this case).

```
where column like '_%[0]1'
```

But the issue is it's even returning me d0101 etc. which I don't want. I just want d0001, or r0001. Can I use it to exactly match pattern, not partially using like?
Any other options in ms-sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL-Server does not really do proper regular expressions but you can generate the search clause you want like this:

```
where column like '_%1' and column not like '_%[^0]%1'
```

The second condition will exclude all cases where you have a character other than `0` in the middle of the string.

It will allow strings of all possible lengths, provided they start with an arbitrary character, then have any number of `0`s and finish with a `1`.  All other strings will not satisfy the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table tst(t varchar(10));

insert into tst values('d0101');
insert into tst values('d0001');
insert into tst values('r0001');

select * from tst where PATINDEX('%00%1', t)>0

or

select * from tst where t like '%00%1'
```

Comment: just check for two consecutive 00 and 1 in end using simple like could help.. just check and let me know

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score -1):

You use the _ to say that you don't care what char is there (single char) and then use the rest of the string you want:

```
DECLARE @ TABLE (val VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @ 
VALUES 
('d0001'),
('f0001'),
('e0005'),
('e0001')


SELECT * 
FROM @ 
WHERE val LIKE '_0001'
```

This code only really handles your two simple examples. If it is more complex, add it to your post.

Comment: the number 1 in the example is value that user passes, so if user passes 289, I'll have to return f0289, so I don't know number of 0s.

Comment: Add a set of sample input data and expected output for each to your post thats shows a wide set of examples you would come across.